# how do I grab value selected from a dropdownlit and insert that into a table in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have built a dropdownlist with value from a db and i also have a textbox where users can input their own value if not found from the dropdownlist. But now, I would like to add those selected item that the user select from the dropdownlist and the word that they may input into the textbox (separated by comma) into a new table after they click into the save button.
[image: over view of the all thing]

And here is the asp.net part 
[image: ascx file]

and the code behind
[image]